# make table content editable and table draggable and resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to make a table which is draggable, resizable and the content of that table is editable. However, when I make the table draggable then the contenteditable property does not works. 
i.e. removing the code below makes the content editable, but I loose draggable property

```
$('#awesomeDiv').draggable({
    containment: 'parent'
});
```

In Google Chrome it works sometimes, and by sometimes I mean if I drag table to the container edge, don't release click, bring mouse on a table cell and click but in Firefox it never works

I have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VNLGb/1/

could any please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

adding an extra event to the table headers and columns

```
onclick="this.focus()"
```

did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

try http://quocity.com/colresizable/

by using this you can resize the table and its cell also

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think I want this. Maybe you would want to look at my edited JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VNLGb/2/ here I have made table header row editable and entire table is resizable and draggable. I figured out the solution after few minutes in washroom in utter silence :)
Anyways thanks for reply